# easy php date configuration

Tags: php, easyphp

i am running easyPHP on localhost in windowsXP

right now its

2011-02-07 19:46:00

but when i try a the PHP function date() it gives me:

2011-02-08 12:43:00

does anybody knows how to configurate this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set your timezone using [`date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York')`](http://php.net/date_default_timezone_set).

Comment: OP seems to be from Bolivia though

Comment: cool, it works and Bolivia is in: date_default_timezone_set('America/La_Paz');

Comment: I assume that this refers to setting `date.timezone = America/New_york` in php.ini

Answer (score 1):

```
date_default_timezone_set('EST');
```

Your timezone like suggested was incorrect. It can be changed through php.ini, however a simple addition to the code itself would be more ideal if php.ini is inaccessible or you just want to be safe about stuff.

Give it a try, let me know if it works. EST may be something different but it seems about right -5:00 GMT?

Good luck! :)

Answer (score 1):

So after toying about with this exact issue for quite some time myself, I came to the following solution. If the rest do not work for you, try the painfully slow and tedious way.

Look for any files named php.ini or httpd.conf in your EasyPHP install folder. In each of these files make sure the following line has your preferred time zone.

```
date.timezone = America/New_york
```

This will work. For me it was one of the httpd.conf files that was overriding my php.ini file. This can make things difficult to detect.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the file `binaries\apache\conf\httpd.conf`
on following `php_value date.timezone` did the trick for me:

```
# PHP Timezone
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  php_value date.timezone "America/Godthab"
</IfModule>
```